# Best way around combine_array with identical keys?

Tags: php

I was using combine_array to update a MySQL table from a CSV file. I thought everything was working like a champ, but it turns out the data source isn't amazing. There are multiple columns with the same name and those columns become the keys in an array. Example take the two arrays:

```
array 1
[0]=>"name"
[1]=>"email"
[2]=>"shoe size"
[3]=>"email"

array 2
[0]=>"Jake Doe"
[1]=>"jake@example.mail"
[2]=>"10.5"
[3]=>""
```

if I was to use [array_combine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)($array1,$array2) I would get:

```
["name"]=>"Jake Doe"
["email"]=>""
["shoe size"]=>"10.5"
```

The problem is that I'd obviously prefer to have the email not get overwritten by a blank value. What I can up with is the function below. What I'm looking for is just a second set of eyes. Is this there a better way to do this? I hate that I have two nested ifs, but I'm not sure how I'd go about making it cleaner or if that's even possible.

```
//array_combine simply overwrites repeat keys, this only overwrites if the value is empty
//if the first instance of the key has a value, it ignores duplicate keys
function new_array_combine($key_array,$value_array){
    foreach($value_array as $key=>$value){
        if(array_key_exists($key_array[$key],$new_array)){
            if(empty($new_array[$key_array[$key]]))$new_array[$key_array[$key]]=$value;
        }else{
            $new_array[$key_array[$key]]=$value;
        }
    }
    return $new_array;
}
```

Comment: what if `$array2[3]` wasn't blank? which value would you want?

Comment: So what is the desired outcome? How *do* you want to combine the values if there are duplicates?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. My only concern is if the value is being overwritten with an empty string. When both values are filled it is the same value. Don't ask why this is the case, I'm only working with the data I've been given... yay!

Answer (score 0):

Blah. Trying to rescue this response, since my first obviously missed the entire point of the post.

If you're only worried about those blank values, then I would say you could walk the arrays once through first, 'cleaning' them by deleting indexes with no corresponding value:

```
<?php
// $a and $b as defined in the example

foreach($a as $k => $v) {
    if(empty($b[$k])) {
        unset($a[$k]);
        unset($b[$k]);
    }
}

$c = array_combine($a, $b);
print_r($c);
```

Output:

```
Array(
    [name] => Jake Doe
    [email] => jake@example.mail
    [shoesize] => 10.5
)
```

**Edit:** To include blank values (but still not let blanks override existing values), first get the unique keys from `$a` and use it to build an empty result array, then just skip blank values while looping through...

```
<?php
// $a and $b as defined in the example

$result = array();
$keys = array_unique($a);
foreach($keys as $key) $result[$key] = '';

foreach($a as $k => $v) {
    if(empty($b[$k])) continue;
    $result[$v] = $b[$k];
}

print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
Array(
    [name] => Jake Doe
    [email] => jake@example.mail
    [shoesize] => 10.5
)
```

Comment: Would have just made it a comment, but I couldn't show my example code and output in a decent format that way. Que sera, sera.

Comment: You're missing the point of the question: what to do if there are duplicates in `$a`?

Comment: Ah, indeed. Reading comprehension FTL. The second `email` completely escaped me. I'll use this remaining soapbox to say that I agree; there's not enough information to answer. If the second *value* wasn't blank, then which one *should* win out? Otherwise, I would say just do yourself a favor and walk the arrays once first, trimming every index from both that has a blank value.

Comment: Alright, made a wholehearted attempt at a real answer, assuming the OP only wants to avoid obliterating values with blanks.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I actually want empty value when there's only one because later I have to use it for a loop to add the values to MySQL and I'd need the array key to exist, even if empty. The data source isn't always complete, but complete or not I need to add as much as possible.

Comment: I've added to my response.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem I see with your program is when key names do not match in each array

```
array 1
[0]=>"name"
[1]=>"email"
[2]=>"shoe size"
[3]=>"email"

array 2
[0]=>"Jake Doe"
[1]=>"jake@example.mail"
[3]=>"10.5"
[4]=>""
```

Suggested modifications:

```
function new_array_combine($a1, $a2){
   $result=Array();
   reset($a1);
   foreach($a2 as &$v){
      $key=current($a1);
      if (!isset($result[$key])||empty($result[$key])) 
          $result[$key]=$v;
      next($a1);
   }
   return $result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for checking about that. It actually won't be a problem (or shouldn't) because array 1 is the the first row of the CSV file. Unless I get a malformed CSV, it should be ok. Any thoughts on how I I could check that? I guess maybe I could just make sure that there are an equal number of keys in the array using `count()`.

Comment: You should use current() and next() function in your second array, so you do not have to care about key names.

Comment: I'd love it if I could do that. Unfortunately, the system that makes the CSV file can have the columns in any order. It's up to the user that generates the CSV file. So I could get `[0]=>"name"` or just as easily something like `[0]=>"Date of birth"`. As best I can figure, this is the only way to have a dependable way to find the data in the array I'm building.

Comment: There might be a misunderstanding somewhere... See the code above in my edited post.